# Updating data attribute after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a page which lists a number of jobs, each job has a button for paid and the button has a data-paid attribute which contains the value of whether it's paid or not.

When the button is clicked, I send a request to my route which updates the payment and returns success along with the status whether its paid or not.

See my button.

```
<button data-id="{{ $r->id }}" data-paid="{{ $r->paid }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm paid">Paid</button>
```

When clicked

```
$('button.paid').on('click', function() {

        var job = this;
        var id =  $(this).data("id");

        $.get('/round/job/' + id + '/paid', function(data){

              $(job).data('paid',data.jh.paid);

              console.log(data.jh.paid);

        });

});
```

When looking at the console, if paid the route returns 1, if not paid it returns 0.

I want to update the data-paid attribute against the button with the value of either 1 or 0.

I thought function would do that but it doesn't update the value it remains at the value when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) is not an accessor for `data-*` attributes, it's both more and less than that. `data` manages jQuery's data cache for the element, which is only *initialized* from the `data-*` attributes. It never *writes* to them.

To actually change the attribute value, use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/data), not data:

```
$(job).attr("data-paid", dta.jh.paid);
```

Of course, if you use `data` throughout your code, and don't care about the actual attribute value except as a starting point, `data` is fine, just don't expect the attribute value to change when you change the data value.

The flip side is that if you don't need the additional features `data` provides, just use `attr`.

Example:

```js
// Get the element
var t = $("#target");

// See what its data value for "foo" is
console.log("Before: t.data('foo') = " + t.data('foo'));

// See what its *attribute* is
console.log("Before: t.attr('data-foo') = " + t.attr('data-foo'));

// Change it
t.data('foo', 'updated');

// See what its data value for "foo" is again
console.log("After:  t.data('foo') = " + t.data('foo'));

// See what its *attribute* is again:
console.log("After:  t.attr('data-foo') = " + t.attr('data-foo'));
```

```html
<div id="target" data-foo="bar"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ArshSingh just waiting the 2 minutes wait and i'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

.data and data atttribute are not the same. If you want to update the attribute do this:

```
$('button.paid').on('click', function() {

        var job = this;
        var id =  $(this).data("id");

        $.get('/round/job/' + id + '/paid', function(data){

              $(job).attr('data-paid', data.jh.paid);

              console.log(data.jh.paid);

        });

});
```